# How to Multiply the first element to the second element using Java Streams

Tags: java

I want to get the product of the current element next element in a list but should only use Java Streams api.

```
Integer[] inputArray = new Integer[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
Integer[] outputArray = new Integer[]{4, 15, 35, 63}
```

Thank you

Comment: What part are you having trouble with: getting the elements or multiplying them together?  Have you written *any* code so far in an attempt to solve this, and if so, what is it?

Comment: One times three is not four...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments `1 * 3` is not four (it's three), otherwise use an `IntStream.range(int, int)` to generate a sequence of indices and perform the multiplication. Like,

```
Integer[] inputArray = new Integer[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int[] outputArray = IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length - 1)
        .map(i -> inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));
```

Which outputs

```
[3, 15, 35, 63]
```

Comment: [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-); I'm not sure why you used `arrayList.stream()`, what is `arrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] inputArray = new Integer[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        Integer[] outputArray = new Integer[inputArray.length - 1];
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Arrays.stream(inputArray).reduce((a, b) -> {
            outputArray[index.getAndIncrement()] = a * b;
            return b;
        });

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray)); //[3, 15, 35, 63] 
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1Mvq3CuH)